# HTML/Javascript - path change for 360 degree picture (to show differen variations)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want to achieve:

I found a script to create a 360 degree image of an object (multiple pictures from different angles). That's not a problem and working, pretty basic but it's working :-)

In phase 2 now, I would like to have 4 buttons (each button for a different color variation of the pictures). So when I click, lets say the the yellow button it should load all pictures from folder img/yellow/.... if I click on red then from img/red/... the picture file names are the same just they show the object in different color in the different folder.

Thats the solution for 360 degree image:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body, ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu {
  width: 400px;
  height: 255px;
  border: 6px solid #ccc;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu ul {
  width: 400px;
  height: 255px;
}
.menu ul li img {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 255px;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>360 rotation Test</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="jquery-script-menu">
    <div class="jquery-script-center">
      <div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 style="margin-top:150px;" align="center";>Mini Image Rotation Plugin Example</h1>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li><img src="images/image1_1.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_2.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_3.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_4.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_5.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_6.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_7.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_8.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_9.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_10.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_11.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_12.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_13.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_14.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_15.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_16.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_17.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/image1_18.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
   var pic_X=$('.list').offset().left;
      var pic_Y=$('.list').offset().top;
   var pic_W=$('.list').width()/2;
     var pic_H=$('.list').height()/2;
   var center_X=pic_X+pic_W;
   var center_Y=pic_Y+pic_H;
   var movestop=pic_W/10;
   $('.list').mousemove(function(event){
  var mouse_X=event.pageX;
  var mouse_Y=event.pageY;
  if(mouse_X-center_X<=0){
   moveImg(mouse_X,mouse_Y,'left')
  }else{
   moveImg(mouse_X,mouse_Y)
  }
   });
     function moveImg(m_X,m_Y,dir){
  var index=Math.ceil(Math.abs(m_X-center_X)/movestop);
  if(dir){
   $('.list li').eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
  }else{
   $('.list li').eq(18-index).show().siblings().hide();
  }
   }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the images are pulled from the folder and then changed via mousemove. Now, I want to have beside the display of the 360 picture some buttons for different colors, I have the same amount of pictures of the object in different colors and as mentioned each color will have a separate folder. How do I change the images path to img/COLOR/imageX.jpg  when I click on a button for a specific color?

I hope thats not to confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable that represents a color. You also have to make sure that all of the images are named in a similar format (with numbers like you have in your example given) with the exception of this color.

An example of the image names would be:

Yellow Images: "yellow1,yellow2,yellow3,etc."

Red Images: "red1, red2, red3, etc."

**JQuery**

```
var color = ""

$(".yellow-btn").click(function(){
 color = "yellow";
 $('.list img').each(function(index){
   this.attr('src', 'images/' + color + (index+1) + ".jpg") // you can change jpg to png as needed
 }
}

$(".red-btn").click(function(){
 color = "red";
 $('.list img').each(function(index){
   this.attr('src', 'images/' + color + (index+1) + ".jpg") // you can change jpg to png as needed
 }
}

$(".blue-btn").click(function(){
 color = "blue";
 $('.list img').each(function(index){
   this.attr('src', 'images/' + color + (index+1) + ".jpg") // you can change jpg to png as needed
 }
}
```

This is assuming that they are all 'jpg' or all 'png'. You would essentially copy that code for the different colored buttons.

Comment: Don't forget to add the full path in the source attribute, something like `this.attr('src', 'images/' + color + (index+1) + ".jpg")` would be setting sources like `images/yellow1.jpg`.

Comment: Good catch on this one!

Comment: One more thing, you missed the dot before the extension in your snippet.

Comment: Thanks guys, but how exactly do I execute the change. Do I have to change the src="" with the color var or do I have to change the content of the div where the images are displayed?

Comment: If you plan on using the same number of images, you would just need to change the `src` attribute with the new images. Naming your images the way I described would simplify the code you would need to reassign the 'src' attributes. Just follow that pattern of the button click and the image naming convention for different colors.

Comment: I still can't fit the pieces together, sorry I think I miss some very basics. So your code is to change a var, but do need one function for each button? Lets say I have 3 buttons (red, blue, yellow), then with the button onclick event I call the related function? Or with the onclick event I change the color var and the resulting color var I use with document.getElementById to change the src for each pic?

Comment: See it now. You need a click event function for each button.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. Thanks much Sharma!

Comment: Glad to have been able to help. Please accept the answer when possible.